# How to recursively flatten a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, dictionary

Thought I had a simple solution for this problem but it turns out I was off.

I have a nested dictionary:

```
my_dict = { "username": "myEmail@email.com",
  "name": { "first": "John", "last": "Doe" },
  "occupation": "Web Developer" }
```

I wrote a recursive function to unwrap it into an existing dictionary:

```
def adder(my_dict, existing_dict):
    for k, v in my_dict:
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            existing_dict[k] = v
        else:
            adder(v.iteritems(), existing_dict)
    return existing_dict


existing_dict = { "role": "employee" }
adder(my_dict.iteritems(), existing_dict)
```

Stepping through the loop, everything goes well until I hit the recursion, then `my_dict` goes from the dictionary to `dictionary-itemiterator object at 0x07f6750086c00`.

I don't see any obvious errors, although seemingly `v.iteritems()` breaks everything (and yet the loop finishes). Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you calling `iteritems` in the recursive call? The recursive call gets an iterator as `my_dict`. On the other hand, iterating over a dict just gets the keys, so `for k, v in my_dict` needs to call `iteritems`.

Comment: Do you need to handle arbitrary levels of nesting, or just once?  What do you want to happen when an inner key collides with an outer key?

Comment: @wim just once, and I can guarantee that the keys won't collide, at least for this small use case, though that's something I might want to think about for the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with the above - iterating on the just the dict itself only iterates on the keys.

Additionally, I think you want to return existing_dict from the function, my_dict is unmodified.  Also, you want to pass the dict back into the function, not the iterator.

```
def adder(my_dict, existing_dict):
    for k, v in my_dict.iteritems():
        if not isinstance(v, dict):
            existing_dict[k] = v
        else:
            adder(v, existing_dict)
    return existing_dict

In [47]: adder(my_dict, existing_dict)
Out[47]: 
{'first': 'John',
 'last': 'Doe',
 'occupation': 'Web Developer',
 'role': 'employee',
 'username': 'myEmail@email.com'}
```