# Get key values for certain fields in JSON response

Tags: python, json, api, key

My json data would look like this:

```
{
   "a":1,
   "b":[
      {
         "c":2,
         "d":{
            "e":3
         },
         "f":{
            "g":4
         },
         "h":[
            {
               "i":5
            },
            {
               "j":6
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Is there a way I can get values for certain fields in the response along with their keys. So from this response, the fields for which I expect values are a, c,e,g,i,j along with the respective keys.
Eg: [a:1,c:2,e:3,g:4,i:5,j:6]. Could this be done?

Comment: we don't have `list` like this in python: `[a:1,c:2,e:3,g:4,i:5,j:6]`, If you want output as `dict` or `tuple` please edit your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recursively flatten a nested dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027151/how-to-recursively-flatten-a-nested-dictionary)

Comment: @OferSadan, No, this is not, because OP have `list` in `dict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function and store `key & value` if only value not list or dict.

```
def get_key_value(dct, res_dct, lst):
    
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                get_key_value(d, res_dct, lst)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            get_key_value(v, res_dct, lst)
        else:
            res_dct[k] = v

            # If you want to store in 'list' you can store as string
            lst.append(f'{k}:{v}')
            
            
            

res_dct = {}
lst = []
get_key_value(dct, res_dct, lst)
print(res_dct)
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
# res_dct
{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'e': 3, 'g': 4, 'i': 5, 'j': 6}

# lst
['a:1', 'c:2', 'e:3', 'g:4', 'i:5', 'j:6']
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked initially. But I got this error on the later period `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: How do you get errors? on what line?

Answer (score 1):

My response contained something like:

```
{
   "a":1,
   "b":[
      {
         "c":2,
         "d":{
            "e":3
         },
         "f":{
            "g":4,
            "k":[
              "l","m"]
         },
         "h":[
            {
               "i":5
            },
            {
               "j":6
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Which resulted in the error. I have made the following fix for it.

```
def get_key_value(dct, res_dct, lst):
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for d in v:
                if isinstance(d,dict):
                    get_key_value(d, res_dct, lst)
                else:
                    lst.append(f'{k}:{v}')
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            get_key_value(v, res_dct, lst)
        else:
            res_dct[k] = v

            # If you want to store in 'list' you can store as string
            lst.append(f'{k}:{v}')
            
res_dct = {}
lst = []
get_key_value(staging_dict, res_dct, lst)
```